# Dispatcher.Invoke() have timeout?

Tags: .net

I think that in my code the Dispatcher.Invoke(action) return (after a several hours) before the action is finish

My question:
Is the Dispatcher.Invoke(action) have default time out ?

Thanks

Isaac Dagan

Comment: Why are you calling `Dispatcher.Invoke` in the first place? This means `run this action on the GUI thread and block while waiting`. If you want something to run in the background, why don't you use `Task.Run`? If you want your action to have a timeout, no matter how it's called, you'll have to code it properly, eg pass a cancellationtoken from a source triggered by a timer

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why would you need to call a long method with Dispatcher? You are calling invoke, so the calling thread will be waiting, too. And if you are calling it in UI thread (usual usage of Dispatcher), it makes even less sense - why would you call long method in UI thread from background thread.

Answer (score 0):

No.
Documentation does not mention it. If you open source code of [Dispatcher](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#WindowsBase/Base/System/Windows/Threading/Dispatcher.cs), you can ensure there is no timeout

```
public void Invoke(Action callback)
{
  Invoke(callback, DispatcherPriority.Send, CancellationToken.None, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(-1));
}
```

`TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(-1)` is a special value, used later in a few validations:

```
public void Invoke(Action callback, DispatcherPriority priority, CancellationToken cancellationToken, TimeSpan timeout)
{
  ...
  if(timeout.TotalMilliseconds < 0 && timeout != TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(-1))
  {
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("timeout");
  }
  ...
}
```

and later:

```
private object InvokeImpl(DispatcherOperation operation, CancellationToken cancellationToken, TimeSpan timeout)
{
  ...
  Debug.Assert(timeout.TotalMilliseconds >= 0 || timeout == TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(-1));
  ...
  InvokeAsyncImpl(operation, cancellationToken);
  ...
  if(timeout.TotalMilliseconds >= 0)
  {
    // Create a CancellationTokenSource that will abort the
    // operation after the timeout.  Note that this does not
    // cancel the operation, just abort it if it is still pending.
    ctsTimeout = new CancellationTokenSource(timeout);
    ctTimeout = ctsTimeout.Token;
    ctTimeoutRegistration = ctTimeout.Register(s => ((DispatcherOperation)s).Abort(), operation);
  }
}
```

And you can explore the call chain deeper.

So, in this case, there is no timeout. It can stop because of other reasons, but not because there was a timeout set initially.